# How to set up a user inside unit tests

Tags: unit-tests

I want to test some methods in my plugin, and some of them required user to be logged in.

I searched everywhere but found nothing of use.

I need to test a method that takes in logged in session token from a user. For that, I need to mock logged user and then get his token using `wp_get_session_token`.

But I'm not sure how to do that.

```
<?php
class Test_Class extends WP_UnitTestCase {

  /**
   * Checks the error for invalid user token
   *
   * @since 1.1.0
   */
  public function test_add_app() {

    $user = $this->factory->user->create();

    wp_set_current_user( 1 );
    $auth_token  = wp_get_session_token();
    $auth_cookie = wp_parse_auth_cookie();

    // I'm checking for validity here but the token seems to be empty
    // so the test fails every time.
  }
}
```

I've read that I can mock data with the factory provided by `WP_UnitTestCase`, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Just few notes:

Looks like you're doing functional/integration tests rather than unit tests in isolation.

Here you're creating a user, but not setting it as the current one:

```
$user = $this->factory->user->create();
wp_set_current_user( 1 );
```

You probably want:

```
$user_id = $this->factory->user->create();
wp_set_current_user( $user_id );
```

Note that cookies aren't set here, because of:

```
tests_add_filter( 'send_auth_cookies', '__return_false' );
```

If you use e.g.

```
add_filter( 'send_auth_cookies', '__return_true' );
```

then you will get an error when `setcookie()` is called from `wp_set_auth_cookie()`:

```
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (
```

The `wp_get_session_token()` is a wrapper of `wp_parse_auth_cookie()`.

Parsing a cookie with `wp_parse_auth_cookie` assumes `$_COOKIE` is set.

Wonder if a fake token string would work in your tests?

Else one could try:

```
$expiration = time() + DAY_IN_SECONDS;
$manager    = WP_Session_Tokens::get_instance( $user_id );
$token      = $manager->create( $expiration );
```

with a verification:

```
$this->manager->verify( $token );
```

and then a cleanup:

```
$this->manager->destroy( $token );
```

Comment: Yeah, I meant integration test (for this case), I'm actually running unit test for other part, but that's not failing :D. The issue is that `$this->factory->user->create()` throws `Undefined index: _wpnonce_create-user` :S

Comment: And this error comes from the above `Test_Class`, even when `$user = $this->factory->user->create();` is the only line in `test_add_app()` ?